# how can i stop variable from updating?

Tags: java

The value of `count` keeps increasing with each loop (32- 64 - 70 etc.). But I need the value to be zero after completing each loop.

public class BinarySearchLecture {

```
 int count = 0;

int binarySearchLecture(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
   if (r >= l) { 
      int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 
      count++;
      if (arr[mid] == x) 
      {
         count++;
         return mid; 
      }
      if (arr[mid] > x) 
      {  
         count++; 
         return binarySearchLecture(arr, l, mid - 1, x);
      }
      else  
      {  
          count++;
         return binarySearchLecture(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
      }
   } else {     
      return -1;
   }
}
```

### }

import java.util.Random;
public class FirstAssignment {

```
 // Driver method to test  
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    BinarySearchLecture bs = new BinarySearchLecture(); 
    int arr[] = new int[65536];
    int n = arr.length; 
    
     
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
    {
         arr[i] = new Random().nextInt(10000000);
    }
    

    
    for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)
    {

         int x = new Random().nextInt(10000000);
        System.out.println( i + "." + "Random search key: " + x );
    


    int result = bs.binarySearchLecture(arr, 0, n - 1, x); 
    if (result == -1) 
        System.out.println("Element not present"); 
    else 
        System.out.println("Element found at index " + result); 
    
         int count = bs.count; // count is an class variable
          
          System.out.println("Number of comparisons are " + count); 
    
     
        //  System.out.format("%32s%10d%16s", x , count , "presnt");
```

}
}}

Comment: Please note that your program is not likely to find any elements even if they exists. Binary searches only work on sorted arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binarySearchLecture method is increasing the count value.

Also you can manually reset it with a method of the class like bs.resetCount()/bs.setCount(0) or something like this. You can add this to the bs class you defined.

```
public class BinarySearchLecture {

int count = 0;
 int binarySearchLecture(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
   if (r >= l) { 
      int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 
      count++;
      if (arr[mid] == x) 
      {
         count++;
         return mid; 
      }
      if (arr[mid] > x) 
      {  
         count++; 
         return binarySearchLecture(arr, l, mid - 1, x);
      }
      else  
      {  
          count++;
         return binarySearchLecture(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
      }
   } else {     
      return -1;
   }
  }

void resetCount(){
  count = 0;
}
}
```

Then your code would look more like this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)
{

     int x = new Random().nextInt(10000000);
    System.out.println( i + "." + "Random search key: " + x );



int result = bs.binarySearchLecture(arr, 0, n - 1, x); 
if (result == -1) 
    System.out.println("Element not present"); 
else 
    System.out.println("Element found at index " + result); 

     int count = bs.count; // count is an class variable
      
      System.out.println("Number of comparisons are " + count); 

 
    //  System.out.format("%32s%10d%16s", x , count , "presnt");
     
   bs.resetCount();
}
```

Another *not performant* solution - create a new instance of the bs class each loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  int x = new Random().nextInt(10000000);
  System.out.println(i + "." + "Random search key: " + x);

  bs = new BinarySearchLecture();

  int result = bs.binarySearchLecture(arr, 0, n - 1, x);
  if (result == -1){
    System.out.println("Element not present");
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("Element found at index " + result);
  }
    int count = bs.count; // count is an class variable

    System.out.println("Number of comparisons are " + count);
}
```

Comment: You should not post Answers where you are guessing. The Question author is not allowed to make edits that invalidates Answers, so if the situation is different from what you expect, you may be locking the Question in for closure without the possibility for re-opening.

Comment: Noted! 
Also, I provide 1 possible solution ... maybe not as efficient but still a solution.

Comment: Thanks! I do not have enough reputation to comment yet, but I have seen in other threads that people answer with some form of suggestions and guesses. Thanks for the pointers! Will follow from now on!